# PHPDoc, file throws exception

Tags: php, cakephp, phpstorm, cakephp-3.0, phpdoc

Is it possible with PHPDoc that a file (in this case a CakePHP template file) throws an exception?

the following code abstract:

```
<?PHP
/**
 * template for Excel Export
 *
 * @var \App\View\SpreadsheetView $this
 *
 *
 * @throws \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception
 */

$this->SPREADSHEET->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$title = "test-title";
$currentSheet = $this->SPREADSHEET->getActiveSheet();
$currentSheet->setTitle($title);
$this->SPREADSHEET->getProperties()
    ->setTitle($title)
    ->setSubject($title . ' ' . date('d.m.Y H:i'));
```

`setActiveSheet` maybe throws an Exception. The `@throws \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception` won't work for the file. PhpStorm reports an unhandled exception. I know that too, the exception is handled outside of this template file. But how do I say that PhpStorm?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and call it (but there, where the file is included). I personally do not see another way...

Comment: @LazyOne Unfortunately this is not possible. Of course I can wrap this in a function, but the CAKE render function (from View) does not know that and I would have to adjust the ViewClass ugly ...

Comment: "@throws" is just a documentation thing, it has no effect on execution. If you need to be able to ignore the exception, then wrap the offending call in a `try / catch` block. Or maybe there's some call you can do first to check whether it will work, like asking for the number of sheets and only set the active one if it exists?

Comment: @GregSchmidt yes, my Question is not an execution Problem. The Script works fine. It's a documentation problem, but it's important because a team member can't be sure if that's what I wanted or if I missed something

Comment: In such case (it's for doc purposes only, for another team member) the best I can think of here is to document it with plain words in that PHPDoc block,e.g. " NOTE: may throw {this exception} when {this} happens..."